# How to access class elements from static vector?

Tags: c++, class, vector, static, member

I have a static vector of `class Town` inside the same class, and I am trying to access it's elements.

**Code:**

```
// town.h
class Town
{
    public:
        static int nrOfTowns;
        static std::vector<Town> *towns;
        std::string name;
};

int Town::nrOfTowns = 0;
std::vector<Town> *Town::towns = NULL;

// main.cpp
/* code */
Town::towns = new std::vector<Town> (Town::nrOfTowns); // initializing vector
Town::towns[0].name; // gives me an error
```

I'm getting an error: *`class std::vector<Town>` has no member named `name`*.

Comment: Why is `towns` a pointer to a vector?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I just realized that there are easier ways to do what I wanted to do (thanks for your answer), but the main idea was that I rarely use pointers and I wanted to practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `towns` is a pointer to a vector but probably it should be a vector:

```
// town.h
class Town
{
    public:
        static int nrOfTowns;
        static std::vector<Town> towns;
        std::string name;
};

int Town::nrOfTowns = 0;
std::vector<Town> Town::towns;

// main.cpp
/* code */
Town::towns.resize(Town::nrOfTowns);
Town::towns[0].name;
```

If you really want it to be a pointer you have to dereference the pointer

```
// town.h
class Town
{
    public:
        static int nrOfTowns;
        static std::vector<Town> *towns;
        std::string name;
};

int Town::nrOfTowns = 0;
std::vector<Town> *Town::towns = nullptr;

// main.cpp
/* code */
Town::towns = new std::vector<Town> (Town::nrOfTowns); // initializing vector
(*Town::towns)[0].name; // gives me an error
delete Town::towns;
```

Comment: I have to admit, I forgot that .resize() was a thing, but isn't it possible to be done with a pointer as well?